# How to replace every time a number appears within range?

Tags: php

I've been looking high and low for this, but I can't seem to find the best way to do this?

I want to basically run through a simple range of numbers 1-20, and every time there is a "3" listed, like 3 or 13, replace that with a value like "thisisa3value"

I'm just a little stumped on the best way that can be done?

This is the code I have so far but it doesn't seem to be working, as it basically prints this out on each number. I want it to basically just ONLY do that for ones that have a 3 associated with it.  Can someone please take a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
foreach (range(1, 20) as $number ) {
echo $number;
echo '&nbsp;';
if ( in_array(3, range(1,20)) ) {
echo '   thisisa3value ';
}
}
?>
```

To reiterate, I just want it to basically print out like this:

1, 2, this is a 3 value, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, this is a 3 value, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 29, 20.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: 17, 18, "19", 20?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Code may help you

```
foreach (range(1, 20) as $number ) {
    echo $number;
    echo '<br>';
    if (strstr($number, '3')) {
           echo '   thisisa3value <br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much. Damn, I wasted so much time, I had no idea of strstr. I'll look into that more.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Mixmastermiike `strstr` is similar to `strpos` except it returns the part of the "haystack" string before the first occurrence of the "needle" string - returning `false` if the string wasn't found. You can do the same thing with `if(strpos($number, "3") !== false){`

Answer (score 2):

Based on your example, any appearance of a `3` is valid, such as `13`.

```
$text = join(', ', range(1, 20));
echo preg_replace('/(\d*3\d*)/', 'this is a 3 value', $text);
```

Produces:

```
1, 2, this is a 3 value, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, this is a 3 value, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Using loop to find the digit in that particular number

```
foreach (range(1, 20) as $number ) {

    if( isDigitPresent($number, 3)){
        echo 'thisisa3value ,';
    }

    else{
        echo $number . ' ,' ;
    }
}



function isDigitPresent( $number , $digit ){

    $found = false;
    while( $number > 0 ){

        if( ($number % 10) == $digit ){
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
        $number = $number/10;
    }

    return $found ? $found : false;
}
```